# Como realizar um comando SQL que preecha varias linhas

Tags: sql, postgresql

Eu possuo uma tabela onde há vários registros de suprimentos, agora será implementado uma coluna nessa tabela onde será salvo uma etiqueta que facilite a encontrar esses suprimentos no estoque, já ajustei a tabela para que todos os registros novos ao serem inseridos na tabela ganhe um número sequencial para esses novos registros, porém preciso adicionar uma etiqueta para os outros suprimentos que já foram adicionados no estoque antes. Há alguma forma de adicionar um número sequencial em vários registros com um comando SQL?

Comment: Já pensou em um update? onde o novo campo for null..

Comment: Acho que oque você precisa, é update incremental, exemplo: 1,2,3,4 etc, correto?

Comment: Acredito que um update incremental resolva realmente @GeiltonXavier, tens como colocar um exemplo em uma resposta?

Comment: vou adicionar um exemplo como resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que o exemplo abaixo, pode resolver o seu problema.

-- Criando tabela temporária para testes

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (id int primary key identity(1,1), counter int default 0)
GO
```

-- Inserindo dados na tabela

```
INSERT INTO #tmp DEFAULT VALUES
GO 10
```

-- Veja como está a tabela

```
SELECT * FROM #tmp
```

-- PREENCHENDO O CAMPO counter  COM VALORES INCREMENTAIS

```
DECLARE @counter int
SET @counter = 0
```

UPDATE #tmp

```
SET @counter = counter = @counter + 1
```

-- Veja novamente a tabela com o campo counter preenchido

```
SELECT * FROM #tmp
```

Comment: tu pode só editar a resposta com o comando SQL completo?

Comment: Eu não consegui implementar isso que você sugeriu

Comment: você chegou a testar esse exemplo?

Comment: Testei mas não consegui fazê-lo funcionar

Comment: não sei se você entendeu o exemplo, quando crio a table  #temp eu crio a coluna counter, essa coluna  counter seria sua coluna, entendeu?

Comment: Ah bom, agora deu certo